# Java System.out.println rounds calculation up

Tags: java

Just starting with Java. Could not find the answer in google. Could someone please explain why result of this operation:

```
System.out.println(20 + -3 * 5 / 8));
```

is: 19?

I assume by default it will print out an integer result only, but why it is rounded up? As the result is 18.125, so I would expect 18 to be printed. Is it always rounding integers up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The associativity of

```
20 + -3 * 5 / 8
```

is such that it's equivalent to

```
20 + (-3 * 5 / 8)
```

`(-3 * 5 / 8)` is rounded towards zero, so it is -1; hence 20+(-1) is 19.

Comment: Is "rounded" the correct term here? Since Integer can not hold any floating numbers it simply drops them.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz ["Integer division rounds toward 0"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2). Yep.

Comment: Okay thank you @murat Karagoz, so (-3*5/8) = -1.85 and it drops the 0.85. Now it make sense!

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  The reason is that integer division rounds towards zero.  So the order of the operations is like this.

```
-3 * 5 = -15
-15 / 8 = -1 (rounded towards zero)
20 + -1 = 19
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as a matter of interest, you could retain the value you want by using the BigDecimal operations to get the right result:

```
BigDecimal resultValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(-3).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(5)).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(8));      
System.out.println(20 + resultValue.doubleValue());
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The question was only my curiosity, why this is happening rather then how to get the accurate value, but thank you anyway :)